# Multithreading thread communication

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

Thread X creates a temporary file for thread Y. Thread Y reads from the temp. When there is no element left in temp, it does something.

Now I rewrite the code and use bounded buffers and condition variables and mutexes instead of temp files. **Now how can thread Y understand that thread X will not send any more items?** simply checking number of elements in buffer wont work sometimes due to context switches. If we use files instead of buffers, we could simply check end of file by fscanf. But now what do we do?

Example partial code of thread Y:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
    while (count == 0) 
        pthread_cond_wait(&c_fill, &mutex); 
    int tmp = get(); 
    pthread_cond_signal(&c_empty); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: Use a counting semaphore instead.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Does X know that it won't send any more items?

Comment: no holgac im afraid not

Comment: so when, why and how does X terminate?

Comment: This is a well-known producer-consumer problem. The obvious solution is using semaphores as suggested above. However, since you're not allowed to use them, thread Y (the consumer) should know how much data is going to be received. Otherwise it'll be wasting precious cpu time in context switches. Thus, in some way, you need to pass total amount of buffer size to thread Y to make it possibly consume the data that producer (thread X) has created for it.

Comment: @BoraBozkurt - what context switches?  It will block on the condvar.

Comment: I'm confused.  If Y doesn't know, and X doesn't know, there can be no answer to your question.

Comment: @MartinJames I mean it could not switch and consume unnecessary time. And by the way, X does know the data. Because it creates a temp file for the Y, right? Therefore, Y should know the total incoming data size.